# Generate drupalSettings in Ajax Callback

Tags: 8, javascript, ajax

I'm returning a form with #ajax functionality in an Ajax response. The form is properly loaded into the page, however it is not #ajaxified, as the drupalSettings are not being returned. In D7, we could generate the JS settings AKA Drupal.settings using the following code:

```
$scripts = drupal_add_js();
if (!empty($scripts['settings']))
{
    $settings = '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, ';
    $settings .= drupal_json_encode(call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $scripts['settings']['data']));
    $settings .= ');</script>';
}
```

I'm trying to find the D8 equivalent of this code, but not having much success. At the moment I'm returning a JsonResponse from my ajax callback, but I'm thinking I probably need to return an AjaxResponse. What I can't figure out is how to pass my generated form to the AjaxResponse, in order for it to return the settings along with the HTML for the form.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm answering my own question. The secret is to use BubbleableMetadata. Here is my code explaining what I did and how it happened. Here is my entire controller response that generates the JSON for the response:

```
 public function ajax_callback($type)
 {
    // Retrieve the form
    $form = \Drupal::service('form_builder')->getForm('Drupal\path\to\Form');

    // Render the form
    $rendered_form = render($form);

    // Get the data from BubbleMetaData
    $data = BubbleableMetadata::createFromRenderArray($form);
    // Retrieve the attachments from the $data
    $attachments = $data->getAttachments();

    // Generate the settings to be sent back with the ajax response
    if(!empty($attachments['drupalSettings']))
    {
        $settings .= '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.extend(drupalSettings, ';
        $settings .= Json::encode($attachments['drupalSettings']);
        $settings .= ');</script>';
    }

    // Send back the rendered form along with the settings
    $response = [
        'content' => $rendered_form . $settings,
        'status' => TRUE,
        'type' => $type,
    ];

    // Return the data as a JsonResponse
    return new JsonResponse($response);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the settings to the section of the array you return in the ajax callback:

```
$form['section']['#attached']['drupalSettings']['mysettings'] = ...
return $form['section'];
```

If you use an html insert command like replace or a dialog command you can do the same for the content you use in this command.

ajax.js will reattach drupal behaviors and settings after it receives the ajax response.

Comment: I'm not trying to insert the settings, I'm trying to retrieve them to send back with my Ajax response.

Comment: I think the js code you are looking for is already in ajax.js, see edit.

Comment: Again, I'm not looking to insert the settings, I need to retrieve the entire drupalSettings from the form, to send back to the browser. I figured out how to do it, you can see my solution below.

Comment: But thank you for your help - sorry I just re-read both my responses and they were a little curt.

Comment: No problem, I try to understand why AjaxResponse is not working for you. Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse::addCommand is also using BubbleableMetadata.